# Are there any films about graphic design?

Tags: resource-recommendations, history

I'm looking for fiction films that are either about graphic design, or have important elements of its history, and I'm a bit stuck.

I'm not trying to find movies that would be *inspiring* for designers (that would be quite broad and subjective), but **movies that touch the subject of design directly**.

Comment: Hmm, if you're looking for fiction films, when Hollywood needs creatives it almost always goes for CAD-phobic architects staring poignantly at drawing boards for good guys and fast-talking advertising execs for villains - designers are too morally ambiguous... I'm sure there's a German and a Spanish film each set around a design agency but I can't remember anything more than that.

Comment: So the documentary on Helvetica is out, then?

Comment: If you're into the whole business designing "steezy" t-shirts for a living, exit from the gift shop is probably a decent watch for you.

Answer (score 7):

Funnily enough, design blog CreativeBloq published a list recently titled ["**The 10 best movies about design**"](http://www.creativebloq.com/industry-insight/movies-about-design-4132431):

*(actually, just realised these are pretty much all feature length documentaries, or documentary-like. Technically they're still movies I think but the question seems to ask for fiction films. Oh well, I'll leave it here anyway)*

1. **Why Man Creates**, 1968, by acclaimed designer Saul Bass (most famous for the iconic Hitchcock posters) and writer Mayo Simon
2. **Helvetica**, 2007, about the creation of the famous font
3. **Design and Thinking**, "examines how design can influence the world of business and social change"
4. **Objectified**, by the maker of Helvetica, about design engineering
5. **Milton Glaser: To Inform and Delight**, see Scott's answer
6. **PressPausePlay**, "Does democratized culture mean better art or is true talent instead drowned out?"
7. **The Universe of Keith Haring**, about the influential artist and social activist.
8. **Sign Painters**, not yet released, about traditionalist American sign makers
9. **The Cool School**, about the LA art scene in the 1940s
10. **Beautiful Losers**, about the 1990s DIY street style

Comment: Thanks for the list. Yep, I was thinking more of fiction films. I've seen some of the documentaries, and they are really good. Maybe I should change the question to include them, I didn't want it to be too broad but I guess there might not be that many films about GD.

Answer (score 3):

The only films I can think of are *[Milton Glaser: To Inform and Delight](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1275724/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* and *[Design & Thinking](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2132308/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)*.

Google turns up [this link](http://www.creativebloq.com/industry-insight/movies-about-design-4132431) on Creativebloq.com.

**[And this is probably the best film every designer should watch. (John Cleese on Creativity)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9rtmxJrKwc)**

As far as I know all films about design are classified as *documentaries*. If they aren't documentaries, they are scripted... and therefore not informative, but meant to be entertaining. Perhaps you mean not "biographies"?

If you are thinking more along hollywood releases, there are films such as *[Crazy People](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099316/?ref_=sr_1)*, or *[Syrup](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0762138/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1)* but these seem to be more about marketing and advertising than actual design to me. And, of course, being scripted they aren't really that realistic in many areas.