# Interesting documetaries on graphic design and any kind of design

Tags: resource-recommendations

I'm looking to be introduced to interesting documentaries in the field of design, I saw [Helvetica](http://www.helveticafilm.com/) and it blew my mind and am looking for films similar to this one.

Comment: This question asks for fictional movies but one of the answers provides a bunch of documentaries: [**Are there any films about graphic design?**](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/20519/8708)

Answer (score 2):

Whoa! Major subject! I think the simplest answer would be the 

### Architecture and Design Film Festival(s)

On that page, you can go through a massive backlog of previous films, filmmakers and subjects.

...or you could search youtube for "design film"....